# Expand bash var inside a string

Tags: bash

I have this:

```
read -d '' foo <<-EOF
FOO "${filename}" BAR {\
\       FOO BAR FOO {BAR};\
\       FOO BAR FOO {BAR};\
};
EOF

filename="bar";

eval echo $foo;
```

And as you might already guessed, I'm trying to expand $filename inside $foo.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Error I'm getting:

```
./test.sh: eval: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./test.sh: eval: line 10: `echo FOO "" BAR { FOO BAR FOO {BAR}; FOO BAR FOO {BAR};};'
```

Comment: try `read -d '' foo <<"EOF"` note the double quotes around EOF

Comment: That's not the problem. I'm getting errors from the eval, which is doing something weird with the }; at the end.

Comment: Yepp, I see (now) :) Whats the meaning of the eval? It fails with syntax error (of course) Btw forget about that double quotes, thats wrong. (my advice was because I know it from another programming language)

Comment: Regardless of $filename will being expanded or not. How should `$foo` contain valid bash syntax? (eval requires this)

Comment: @hek2mgl $foo should be just a string, as in I don't want to expand $foo, I just want to expand $filename

Comment: can you declare `filename` before the `read`?

Comment: but echo eval "$foo" will do evaluate $foo as code

Comment: @dogbane Thats the question: How can $filename declared later or changed after usage in the string (as far as I'm understood)

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, that's the problem. Where should eval be?

Comment: @alexandernst Will have to make some tests on my own

Comment: What is the goal? Do you want to pass that entire thing including semicolons as arguments to echo, or are those braces supposed to be command groups and you're trying to execute a function named `FOO`? Right now you're evaluating two commands and one invalid command. Also I have no idea what you mean by "expand $filename inside $foo".

Comment: @ormaaj Final goal is produce a string with the exact same structure as $foo but with $filename expanded.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to put shell code into a string. If so, you should avoid that and use a function if possible. In the unlikely event the `eval` really is necessary, you wouldn't want a filename expanded literally. What the string is and what you're planning on doing with it affect the answer greatly...

Comment: @ormaaj What this script is generating is a "config" file, and I need the filename expanded for it to work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- quote the word `EOF` so that any variables in the heredoc are not expanded.
- escape the semicolons
- add the `-r` option to `read` so that it does not treat backslash as an escape character

Try this:

```
read -r -d '' foo <<-"EOF"
FOO "${filename}" BAR {\
\       FOO BAR FOO {BAR}\;\
\       FOO BAR FOO {BAR}\;\
}\;
EOF

filename="bar"

eval echo "$foo"
```

Output:

```
FOO bar BAR {  FOO BAR FOO {BAR};  FOO BAR FOO {BAR};};
```

Comment: Thanks too :) ... I don't get why eval parses this fragment without syntax error. Could you explain that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible (update: read the accepted answer ;) what you are trying to do. This is because the `eval` command requires that that `$foo` contains valid bash syntax.

I would use bash's string manipulation operators to replace `$filename`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -d '' foo <<'EOF'
FOO "$filename" {
       FOO BAR FOO BAR;
       FOO BAR FOO BAR;
};
EOF

filename="bar";

echo "${foo/\$filename/$filename}"

filename="bar2";

echo "${foo/\$filename/$filename}"
```